# Magento - Calling another layout from one layout file

Tags: php, magento

On Magento, and if I have something like on PHTML file:

```
$this->getChildHtml('myblock');
```

How to set a layout template file but without using blocks? I want inside PHTML calling another PHTML file directly using "getChildHtml()".

Or what put inside blocks to set template files?

```
<block type="module/some_path" name="some_path.something" template="xxx.phtml">

                                <reference name="myblock">
                                    <template>xxxx.phtml</template>
                                </reference>                                

</block>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> catalog/product/popular.phtml where to set your module file path

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->
           setTemplate('catalog/product/popular.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```